# Faulty cron job: safe to delete?

Tags: perl, cron, cpanel

One of the automatically generated cron jobs, namely:

```
2 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/quickinstall/scripts/checkupdates.pl
```

outputs this:

```
    Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/JS/Variations.pm line 20, near "$filename =~ s{/js2"
      (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 19)
            (Missing operator before js2?)
    syntax error at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/JS/Variations.pm line 20, near "$filename =~ s{/js2"
    Global symbol "$filename" requires explicit package name at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/JS/Variations.pm line 21.
```

and many other errors.

Would it be safe to delete this cron job? especially considering that:

- it is faulty in the first place;
- I don't have access to the Perl script in question and can't fix it;
- quickinstall modules (such as WP and Moodle) properly check for updates themselves.

I'm using a shared hosting on HostGator and, as such, don't have a shell access; all I can do is work thru cPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with cPanel, so I can't address that aspect of the question, but, from the Perl side, I can tell you that deleting the cron job will do no (additional?) harm.  Because there's a syntax error in the Perl code, the checkupdates program is already not running (and, indeed, *can't* run).

Checking with any appropriate vendor to see whether they can provide a fixed copy of `Cpanel::JS::Variations` (the source library which contains the actual error) would likely be a good idea, as it may be used by other pieces of Cpanel which actually are important, but the cron job isn't doing anything other than generating email to tell you it failed.

Comment: OK Dave, I deleted it; so far the flight is nominal. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that cron entry is not a default cron entry added by cPanel. If the cron is faulty you can just delete it. I jave just checked on my cPanel/WHM server, I do not have such a cron job, I do not have that **quickinstall** folder. Most probably you are using some 3rd party apps (like softaculous for example) so that's why the cron is there. You could also open a support request to HostGator and see what they say.

Comment: Yes Bogdan, you are right. I suspect that particular cron job was added automatically when I installed WordPress module via the Quickinstall tool in cPanel. As for HostGator's techsupport... They are a weird bunch: the only way to get help is request a ticket from *their side* thru a live chat, which drops connection all the time :/